# The use of the English word "yes" in spoken French

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, exclamations

I have been watching a French TV series (Les Témoins / Witnesses) with English subtitles.

In one episode I was surprised to hear the main character, a female cop, clearly say "*Yes!*" (more to herself than the other person) during a phone conversation in which she obtained crucial information about a criminal she was pursuing. Then, after the call ended, she whispered more than spoke "*Yes! Yes! Yes!*" to herself. Her mood was a mix of relief, excitement, triumph and satisfaction.

This was the only occasion in the entire series that I noticed anyone using English, and I have never personally heard "*yes*" used in any French conversation. Was this an just an anomaly, or is "*yes*" now being used in spoken French? If so:

- If it is used at all, is it only ever used as an exclamation, and never in reply to a question?
- In what circumstances would its use be generally accepted and understood?
- How common and widespread is its use?

For the exact context, the phone conversation I am referring to is in [Series 2, Episode 6 of Les Témoins](http://www1.sockshare.net/?movie=/play/dZYK3WjG/witnesses-season-2/6) between about 49:25 and 49:40.

Comment: I notice that the popular French YouTuber Cyprien says it a lot.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I don't know if it is relevant but here is Ngram result that depicts an increasing trend of using yes in French. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yes&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyes%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes in French ? Ha! You mean ***Yai**ssssssss!* ;-) At the moment you realize, understand, learn that something important for you is sucessfull / correct / right / true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer with a French point of view, I don't know how it is for French speakers outside of France.

We do use `Yes` as an exclamation, when something cool happened to us / when we won something as you pointed out in your question.
It can also be used as a reply, when something "cool" happened to one of your friend, example:

> - Je pars en vacances en Amérique la semaine prochaine.
>    - Ha yes ! profite bien !

We sometimes use it to replace `oui`, for example:

> - Est-ce que tu pourrais m'envoyer le lien de la vidéo de la dernière fois ?
>   - Yes ! Je te fais ça tout de suite !

I couldn't tell how often we use `Yes`, the only thing I can tell you is that we don't use it in really formal situations.

I guess we use it only to sound "cooler" :)

Comment: As sad as I feel about it, you are perfectly right. I really noticed this trend was happening when [a graphic novel](https://www.labandedu9.fr/article-7-nains-par-labandedu9-432.html) I was reading, and not actually a bad one, made use of this type of exclamation. From then, there was no going back to my happy unknowing state. +1

Comment: Something I forgot to ask is whether "_yes_" is less likely to be used by older people. Is that the case?

Comment: @skomisa I depends which older person you're talking about. I would guess the proportion of them using it is much lower, but I have heard people in their sixties make occasional use of it.

Comment: In Quebec, we have the base use (something cool happening to yourself), but not the other ones.

Comment: In Belgium this is also quite common among the younger generations. My 6 years old kid uses it although she has no knowledge of English

Comment: @LaurentS. Or perhaps: she has no knowledge that she has knowledge of English (assuming that _"yes"_ has not risen to the level of being considered a French word).

Answer (score 2):

Teenagers and young adults use ’yes !’ when they succeed in doing something, when something great happens to them.

Comment: Pas sûr que l'on puisse qualifier quelqu'un de 40 ou 50 ans de jeune adulte, mais Ok.